# Where can a European buy a US prepaid credit card with a registration address in the US?

Tags: usa, payment-cards, eu-citizens

I am from the Netherlands and I want to registrar my drone to get a licence. This can be done with an US prepaid credit card with a registration address in the US. 
Next month I would be flying to Denver Colorado USA.

What is the easiest way to obtain this card?

Comment: in a word, it's impossible to do this these days.  maybe 15 years ago at best.  "they've thought of that" , you know?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an address in the US yet?  Do you have a social security number?  You will likely need both for a rechargeable prepaid debit card.  Same for a secured credit card (ie you open an account with $500, they give you $500 credit line).

You might consider a Visa Gift Card, which can be bought and used by anyone. But if the registrar for drones is limiting registration to US based cards, they maybe able to detect a gift card and block it to avoid registrations by foreigners.

Comment: The FAA doesn't really care what your nationality is. There are lots of foreign-registered aircraft. The drone process is new and different though.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Obviously the FAA has some concerns about something if they mandate a US based card.  But I don't know the exact rules so won't get into a debate over it.